# installing java on a linux server

Tags: java, linux, jar

completely new to this so apologise for the question.

I have current been asked to deploy a jar on a linux server at work. I have sucessfully logged into ther server using ssh and transferred my jar on to it. However when I run any java command it says command not found.

I ran

> locate java

and

```
locate jar
```

which both return, so im guessing java is installed? What do i need to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "_which both return_"? Do they return the location of those command, or do they return nothing at all?

Comment: you should ask this question here: http://superuser.com/

Comment: My guess is that you have not `java` installed, give us some more information about the distribution you use.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your path has not been set up to fit your Java needs. You can do either of two things:

1. Type out the full path of where java is located, and use this full path instead of "java".
2. Edit your `PATH` to include java. Here's some information on how this is done: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check to make sure that java is installed and the path for it is set too.

Whe you type `locate jar` it's most likely going to return any other jar including the one you have just added. To know if java is installed, you should instead use the following command `java`, if the result is something like `the program cannot be found...` then it means there is not java. You could also use `java -version` which will also tell you which version is installed. If it's for running purposes then you will be good with that.

Answer (score 0):

First try the command which java, it would show you if you have java installed if not download it and install,run it. Then you can run the jar file as per you requirement. This link shows you how to install and configure java.

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker